# How many dart files is too many for a flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I have been developing a real estate app and the app is getting complicated as I keep adding more screens and features. Right now I have 193 Dart Files.
I would like to know how many dart files is too many, and would affect app performance and size.
Thank you
best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any definition of "too many". Maybe your app is not only about real estate but also a "super app", but in anyway, as long as you can easily add a new feature or easily debug/fix bug -> it would not be a problem.

About the **size**, it is increasing because of many files, I agree. But about the **performance**, it depends how you manage your app, such as which needs to loading at the moment, which needs to have lazy loading, which needs to do in background...

Summary, many files can increase app's **size**, but **performance** depends on you, and many files maybe *not a problem*. If you know about *CLEAN* architecture, it has very very many boilerplate code :) Don't worry.